# Initializing pipeline object with crawler in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Based on [Scrapy : Program organization when interacting with secondary website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476106/scrapy-program-organization-when-interacting-with-secondary-website) , I have:

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.crawler = crawler
```

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the code especially the lines at the beginning listed above. Why would you initialize the pipeline object with a crawler. I have a lot of pipelines where I don't include this or any init method. What is the purpose of initializing the pipeline with a crawler?

Comment: no need for that at all as you already checked that it works without it. The example was showing the need of that object, because it was going to use it on the `process_item` method later.

Comment: So would this be an example of composition: instantiating a pipeline object with an included crawler instance so as to take advantage of the latter's features ( scheduler, etc)

Comment: it is not "creating" an instance of the crawler, just making the same instance accessible within the pipeline through that variable

Comment: I don't have a good understanding of how the parts fit together in scrapy. Could I ask you to expand on that. How is a a crawler involved here?

Comment: `from_crawler()` is a classmethod that allows you to pass some `crawler` attributes to your pipeline class. The crawler is a bit in scrapy that holds and manages everything together. This particular bit of architecture might be a bit confusing but I find [this page](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) from the documentation to cover it pretty well!

Comment: Thank you, that does help, although the crawler is not in the diagram .Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169756/how-to-get-the-number-of-requests-in-queue-in-scrapy , I was getting the impression that the scheduler is in the crawler, but I'm not sure I see it in https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/crawler.py